# why length() is used for getting array's size in json parsing in Android?

Tags: java, android

while normally we use a length variable for getting size of arrays
for example this is a snippet

```
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(getmData());
JSONArray itemsArray = jsonData.getJSONArray(FLICKR_ITEMS);
for (int i= 0;i<itemsArray.length();i++) {
    JSONObject jsonPhoto =itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = jsonPhoto.getString(FLICKR_TITLE);
    String author = jsonPhoto.getString(FLICKR_AUTHOR);
}
```

Comment: Because a `JSONArray` is not a Java array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not accessing an array, but rather invoking a method on `JSONArray`.

It is a bad practice to allow direct field access, since it screws up inheritance, prevents you from controlling who can set its value, forbids synchronization etc when such things are required, so the length field is exposed via a method. See Effective Java 2nd ed Item 14:

> In public classes, use accessor method, not public fields

Answer (score 0):

The `length` member of a normal inbuilt array is final so it can be safely exposed directly. You could try to change it but the compiler won't let you.

A `JSONArray` however is dynamic which means its length can change by adding or removing items from it. It is not safe to expose the length variable directly because you could change it, likely breaking the object causing exceptions, undefined or unexpected behaviour, etc. For example how would you access the `20th` item after you change the length to be `5`.

Instead only an accessor method is provided, `length()`, for getting the length. The length variable is managed internally by the `JSONArray` class when calling methods that would affect its size such as `put()` and `remove()`.

You can compare this to a regular `List`. You get its length by calling its `size()` method. It is designed like this for the same reason.

Comment: "Its length could change" isn't a good reason in and of itself not to expose the field directly. Why not just make it non-final? Giving the reason would give a more complete answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner The length of an array **cannot** change, hence it **is** final, therefore making it **safe** to expose. A `JSONArray`/`List` **can** change in length, so its length **cannot** be final. Exposing it directly is **not** safe because the programmer could (accidently/wrongfully) change it.

Comment: I was suggesting that you add such information to your answer. I'm quite familiar with the reasons :) but was playing devil's advocate with your current answer. However, "final = safe to expose field" isn't quite true. See the item in effective Java mentioned in my answer.